# Parsing Python List values from column in pandas data frame??? Data cleaning help me please

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am new to the community and data science.  I have found this hub to be of extreme value and hope to be an additive contributor one day.

VS Code: Python: Pandas Question

I am working with a data set in VS code utilizing python.  Currently I am cleaning this data set up and I am trying to parse 2 values from a list of 3 item for every column in a series.

This column of the dataframe was originally a string and I need to convert it to a numeric data type.  So far I have split the values in the column and created a list within each row of this column.

How do I create 2 new columns with just the numeric values from this series where all of the values are lists in a python dataframe?

I would like to create columns 'Point_1' and 'Point_2' from the numeric values using a for loop.  what is the best way to do this?

Below is an image of my IDE with the code snippet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to go from a column with a list/tuple of values to multiple columns is to transform each row in your dataframe into a row with multiple values and then stack those new rows vertically. The `apply()` method of the original dataframe does both of these operations:

```
split_point_col.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]),
                      axis = 1)
```

When you do `apply()` with `axis=1`, the lambda function you supply is called for each row in the original dataframe. So the variable `x` in the lambda is going to be one row from the dataframe for every call.

The rows of a dataframe are Pandas.Series objects so they have a row index, and a tuple of associated values. Each row is passed with an index of 0 so the easiest way to access the values from the row is to grab the values at index 0 with `x[0]`.

The values (a single tuple) can then be passed to `pd.Series()` that generates a series object from the tuple, inserting each of the three elements of the tuple at indices 0, 1 and 2.

After the lambda has been invoked, the new Series object will be stacked on top of each other and become a dataframe. This happens automatically with apply.

Note that this will create three columns per row the first one will just have the string `'Point'` in it. Since you only want two columns for the coordinates, you can use `pd.Series(x[0][1:])` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much you have been a huge help!!